# Optimal way to filter the left join result in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm doing a select using 4 tables and one of them has 6.7M rows. In the table_1 I have some main codes, and in the table_2 (the one with 6.7M rows) I have subcodes of the main codes, like this:

```
Table_1      Table_2
| code |      | code |
| A1   |      | A1A  |
| A11  |      | A1B  |
| A2   |      | A2A  |
| A22  |      | A22  |
```

The rule is, the code always has one or two letter and a number (with 1, 2 or 3 digits), and the subcode is the same code, or has the same code + one letter. So, I did the left join like this:

```
SELECT t1.code, t2.subcode
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
ON t2.subcode LIKE t1.code || '%' AND
substr(replace(t2.subcode, t1.code, ''), 1, 1) not in ('0', '1', '2', '3', 
'4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
```

It's works, but, because Table_2 has 6.7M results, even with the 2 columns having indexes, the query (with joins with the other 2 tables) it's taking 6~7 minutes to resolve and I need this in a shorter time.
So, someone knows how to optimize this query?

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on `table2` just on the code:

```
create index idx_table2_code
    on table2(case when substr(code, 3, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
                   then substr(code, 1, 2) else code
              end);
```

Then use this as the expression in the `join`:

```
select t1.code, t2.subcode
from table_1 t1 left join
     table_2 t2
     on t1.code = (case when substr(code, 3, 1) between 'A' and 'Z'
                        then substr(code, 1, 2) else code
                   end);
```

The `join` should be able to use the index.

Comment: or better yet, split that into two separate fields.  having two fields combined in one, rubs me so wrong.

Comment: I did some simple examples, but the codes are not so standard. A code can be A10 and the subcode A10_B2. I have an index on the column, but just a simple index, because there are so much variants of subcodes. 
But I will try to think about another index and if I get success I come here to respond

Comment: I edited the "code rules" on the question, because they are more complex that i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the use of `like` and `in` in your join conditions.  How about using something like:

```
SELECT t1.code, t2.subcode
  FROM table_1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
                 ON t2.subcode = t1.code || 'A' OR
                    t2.subcode = t1.code || 'B' OR ...
```

if you only have a few subcodes, only the first few letters of the alphabet, doing it like this might be a lot faster.  Or, you could try

```
SELECT t1.code, t2.subcode
  FROM table_1 t1
       LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
            ON SUBSTR(t2.subcode, 0, LENGTH(t1.code)) == t1.code AND
               SUBSTR(t2.subcode, LENGTH(t1.code) + 1, LENGTH(t2.subcode)-LENGTH(t1.code)) IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'...)
```